# HTML / PHP form, upon completion display message, then redirect

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have created a form in HTML, using PHP to gather the information submitted, send it to my database and also email myself with the users input.

At the moment, when the user submits the form they are taken to a page which thanks them for their enquiry using this code:

```
mail($emailID, $subject, $body, $headers );
    echo "<h4>Thank you for sending us an enquiry. We will get back to you as soon as possible. </h4>  ";
```

Can this message be set to display for a short period of time, then redirect to the previous URL? I know the following javascript can be used to achieve this however if someone doesn't have javascript enabled, they will be stuck:

```
    mail($emailID, $subject, $body, $headers );
    echo "<h4>Thank you for sending us an enquiry. We will get back to you as soon as possible. </h4>  ";
    echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'http://www.mysite.com/page.html';\",1500);</script>";
```

Is there a simple PHP option to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could try

so i.e.

```
mail($emailID, $subject, $body, $headers );
echo "<h4>Thank you for sending us an enquiry. We will get back to you as soon as possible. </h4>";
flush(); // Will execute the above and continue
sleep('seconds'); //if you want to add some waiting time    

// More PHP code here
header('Location: url');
```

Comment: Hi just tried this but after say 5 seconds it wouldn't execute the header, when you say more PHP code, what could I insert?

Comment: got the following error: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Comment: Try adding ob_flush() or ob_clean() it should clear the buffer